# Display specific parts of array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

This code is creating an array, `dateArray`, from the parameter, `date3`, which is being passed through a function.

The data being passed through that function is a full date in the format, `"12312015"`. The variable `month` should break off the first two characters of the array, `dateArray`. Then the variable `Smonth` converts the month array back into a string. The last line is then supposed to display the string `"12"` through the HTML form in a textbox. When the button on the form is pressed the function runs but it displays nothing.

```
var dateArray = [date3];
var month = dateArray.slice(1, 2);
var Smonth = month.toString();

VerifyForm.dobBox.value = Smonth;
```

Comment: And the question is ..... ?

Comment: Why, when I run the function, isn't it displaying the first 2 characters as I would like it to do?

Comment: Display where exactly?

Comment: I don’t see a function anywhere.

Comment: @NathanThompson why the random ` after `Smonth;`?

Comment: There is a textBox in the html document called "dobBox"

Comment: you need to slice dateArray[0].slice(1,2);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are creating an array `dateArray` with only 1 item in it which is the date string, so slicing it from 1 to 2 will return an empty array not the first and second characters of the original string.

Since `date3` is a string, you can use [String.substring()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) to extract the first 2 characters

```
var month = date3.substring(0, 2);    
VerifyForm.dobBox.value = month;
```

Answer (score 0):

After this

```
dateArray = [date3];
```

the dateArray contains single element at index 0. And here

```
dateArray.slice(1, 2);
```

you are trying to get range from 1 to 2 elements. But they are not there.
So you are getting nothing - empty array.

Answer (score 0):

The dateArray you're creating is an array with a **SINGLE** value.

the **slice** function you're using is used to 'slice' up arrays with **MULTIPLE** values.

To achieve what you're trying to achieve you need to use **substring**.

Example:
VerifyForm.dobBox.value = date3.substring(0,2);